# Unable to copy files from local disk to HDFS

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, word-count

i have successfully installed ubuntu 12.04 and hadoop 2.4.0.

after entering the jps command i find the output as below

```
4135 jps
2582 SeconadaryNameNode
3143 NodeManager
2394 Namenode
2391 Datanode
3021 ResourceManager
```

now i want to run the wordcount example.

i created a .txt file with some content in it

now whenever i try to copy this into hadoop hdfs by following this command

```
hdfs -copyFromLocal /app/hadoop/tmp/input.txt /wordcount/input.txt
```

("wordcount" in the path is a directory which i have created)

but it shows

```
unrecognised option: -copyFromLocal
could not create the java virtual machine
```

what i am doing wrong?

Comment: you are missing hdfs command argument (dfs). try $ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal

Comment: And this is not a wordcount issue. I changed the title of your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The commands you are using are older ones. Try,

```
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /wordcount/input
hadoop fs -put /app/hadoop/tmp/input.txt /wordcount/input/input.txt
```

You'll need to specify the output directory to be `/wordcount/output` in this case and it should not exist before you run the job. If it does, the job will fail. So you can remove the directory as,

```
hadoop fs -rm -R /wordcount/output
```

**Edit:** To see the output files, check:

```
hadoop fs -ls /wordcount/output
```

To see the output on the console, use this:

```
hadoop fs -cat /wordcount/output/part*
```

**Edit 2:** The newer Hadoop CLI uses:

```
hdfs dfs <your_command_here>
```

For example,

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

Also, if you want to read `gzip` files, you can use this,

```
hdfs dfs -cat /wordcount/output/part* | gzip -d -u
```

Comment: now how to run it m using this following command hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-xamples-*.*.* jar wordcount input output but its showing error

Comment: k it worked after replacing input and output by wordcount/input and wordcount/output respectively but how can i access the output means where will it show the total no of occurrences of words

Comment: Updated the answer for your queries.

Comment: thnx how to write your own code to analyze 2GB around data in hadoop

Comment: The technique doesn't really matter on the amount of data. That is the beauty of MapReduce. The code which works on MBs will work for PBs of data. The algorithm depends on your problem.

Comment: but actually am asking is how to write the code and where to writhe code to analyze data. like the wordcount prog is already written but i want to know how to make my own mapreduce code as am a newbie hope you could help me out

Comment: You'll find a source jar having `-src` in the file name for all the examples provided with Hadoop. You can read the code there. Or just search for MapReduce wordcount online and you'll find many examples.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `dfs`

`hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /blar /blar`

IMO Scalding is the best tool to get started writing MapReduce programs. It's as concise as Pig but as flexible as Java.